# requete ajax findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

i had a project contains many problems and i want to get one problem with findOne not all the problems in this project  can someone correct for me my code.

this requete ajax which display for me all problems of this project

```
<div id="people"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data;
    var id = "<%= id %>";
     var problemes = [];
     $.ajax({
     url : "/projets/"+id+"/ajax",
     data : data,
      cache : false,
       dataType : "json",
        error : function(request, error) { 
       alert("Erreur : responseText: "+request.responseText);
     },
       success : function(data) {
      data = data.problemes;
         data.forEach(function(element) {
       var obj = {
         id: element._id,
         parentId:null,
         name:element.text
      }
     problemes.push(obj);
      });
        console.log('aa0', problemes);
      console.log('aa', problemes);
         var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
         var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        color: 'FF0000',
        primaryFields: ["name", "title"],
        photoFields: ["image"],
        dataSource: problemes
     });
     } 
      }); 
</script>
```

and this a route which returns a json data

```
router.get("/:id/ajax", function(req, res){
        Projet.findById(req.params.id).populate("problemes").exec(function(err, data){
            console.log("data", data);
           if(err){
              console.log(err);
           } else {
              res.status(200).json(data);
           }
        });

  });
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what is the problem ?

Comment: i had project contains many problems and i want to get one problem selected @RohitMahajan

Comment: So, you select one problem from some control (eg. `<select>`) and the idea is return all the data of that selected item. Right?

Comment: According to your mongoose query, you fetch some project by `id`. Then, from which or where do you get the problem `id`? Once you have the problem `id` you just need to filter the `problems` array searching by the `id`: `problems.find(prob => prob.id === selectedId)`.

Comment: can you please correct for me my code @gugadev

Comment: Update the code to know from which control you get the problem id. Currently we can only see the `project` id that sends by url.

Comment: i add "problems.find(prob => prob.id === selectedId)" where in my code @gugadev

Comment: In the ajax success callback. The logic is really simple: Get the project, extract the problems and loop over them to get the problem with the id that you want.